# react-native-image-crop-picker cropping frame height fixed after a limit

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` in my react naive android project to crop images. After setting `freeStyleCropEnabled = true` in my app I am able to do freestyle cropping but after a certain limit, I am not able to reduce the height of the frame to be cropped. Any solution regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do free style cropping by setting `freeStyleCropEnabled = true` by using
`react-native-image-crop-picker` library for a certain extent. for more free style cropping use `react-native-image-crop-tools` library.

Comment: Using freeStyleCropEnabled = true with react-native-image-crop-picker worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

"freeStyleCropEnabled" is allowed for only Android.
You can use cropperToolbarTitle: 'Move and Scale' for the IOS.